# How to set minimum number of rows displayed in a rdlc report table?

Tags: sql-server

How to set minimum number of rows displayed in a rdlc report table? 
If database return 5 rows only but i want 15 rows even 10 rows are displayed blank.

Comment: Here is my post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268109/how-to-set-minimum-row-of-table-in-rdlc-or-ssrs-report/37268110#37268110

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of limiting the number of rows displayed in a SSRS report .The way you do it is by writing an expression on a group

```
 =Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 20)
```

And also set Page Break at start and Page break at end

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to mind is that you can add additional rows with empty data to the dataset that is passed to the rdlc.

This can be done in a stored procedure (or multi-statement function) that's used to populate the data table or it can be done directly against the data table in the code of your application prior to handing it off to the report.