# How to set minimum row of table in rdlc or ssrs report?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

Let say I want to set minimum row in the table, When my data is not full in the table then just insert blank row to full fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question looks so easy but it's really hard to find a solution to do it

So I need to share it here

1.In the table set header and 1 bound detail row

2.Insert blank row in the table as much as you want to fill the row (Outside Group)

3.Right click on the second row (the first is detail row) and click
right click and click Row Visibility note: You can input the next step code into Hidden Properties to but I found it not works properly so I recommend this way

[image: right click and click Row Visibility]

4.Click Show or hide based on an expression then insert this code then OK

```
 =IIF(CountRows() < 2, False, True)
```

[image: Insert following Code]

5.Repeat the steps on every blank row and change condition number

Ex. the third row insert this code

```
=IIF(CountRows() < 3, False, True)
```

Ex. the fourth row

```
=IIF(CountRows() < 4, False, True)
```

What it does if your data has to use that row then it just hides the blank row and replace with your data

That it.

I post this because I hope to found this solution on the first minute when I was searching about this

Comment: Works like a charm. I've lost count of how many times I had this issue. I got it done by including empty rows in the dataset, but sometimes that brings some problems with borders (depending on which borders are required). Thanks,